# Dynamic URL in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm so new to django. Please a quick help will be much appreciated.

```
url(r'^shops/(?P<Newshop_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.shop_single, name='singleshop')
```

this path is given me page not found error.

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class SliderTitle(models.Model):
    slider_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.slider_title

class Slider(models.Model):
    slider_type = models.OneToOneField(SliderTitle)
    slider = models.FileField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.slider_type)

class ShopCategories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class NewShop(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ShopCategories)
    main_image = models.FileField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Enter tagline here2')
    description = models.TextField(default='enter shop description')
    shop_image = models.FileField()
    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^shops/(?P<Newshop_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.shop_single, name='singleshop')
```

views.py

```
def shop_single(request, Newshop_id):
    cat1 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=1)
    cat2 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=2)
    cat3 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=3)
    cat4 = NewShop.objects.filter(category_id=4)
    name1 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=1)
    name2 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=2)
    name3 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=3)
    name4 = ShopCategories.objects.filter(id=4)

    return render_to_response('shop_single.html', {'shop_name1': name1, 'shop_name2': name2, 'shop_name3': name3,
                                             'shop_name4': name4, 'Shop_cat1': cat1, 'Shop_cat2': cat2,
                                             'Shop_cat3': cat3,
                                             'Shop_cat4': cat4, })
```

[my DB from phpmyadin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTU82.png)

Comment: what is the stack trace you see ?

Comment: URLs containing a regex like `(?P<Newshop_id>[0-9]+)` are usually used to *retreive* an existing object record. The `Newshop_id` variable is apparently never used in your view, meaning you are not retrieving anything. What do you intend to happen in this view?

Comment: You haven't even said what URL you are actually going to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are never using newshop_id in your view.

So you need not to pass that newshop_id in your view and your url.

Comment: Thanks alot, i had to just read the full documentation of URL again. I had it fixed. Learning a programming language requires lots of patience and persistence